# Downloading Uploaded Files using spring. Tomcat Server randomly freezes

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

So I want to download the uploaded files
however after multiple request and cancelled download, the server randomly freezes.
server logs doesnt show any error.
it just freezes and can't accept new request until tomcat is restarted.
any idea why?

here's the code of the downloading part
http://pastebin.com/5zS7Twti

Thanks!

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons. We can only guess without your code. E.g. you have a Map of files which is never cleared so your app just have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt notice that on the other part of my code, one of the function calls didnt close the hibernate session. this caused the web server to freeze after reaching the maximum number of session allowed.